# How to configure high availability for azure timer trigger function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services, architect

we have created azure durable function with timer trigger. We are not using Azure front door. Currently, function is deployed at east US2 & Central US region with Active -Active configuration.

Here problem is, both functions are executing and processing same data twice which is incorrect. I want to setup this configuration as Active-Passive but how it should be architect?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You have to synchronize the work yourself by setting a lock for example, preventing the other timer from doing work when the work is already done. Or you disable the timer trigger function in the failover region, which means that in case of a failover you need to enable them yourself. Of course you could script that.

See also [this blogpost](https://ivision.com/blog/azure-functions/) describing the solution contained in this answer.